# Adding angular js into Bitnami mean stack

Tags: angularjs, bower, mean-stack, bitnami

I have successfully activated All the js program for MEAN stack except Angualar.

I used but I can't be able to understand the process of making .bowerrc in my application directory.

I am following the instructions from [Bitnami MEAN stack installing related wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_MEAN_Stack#How_do_I_download_and_install_MEAN_Stack.3f).

but when I try to write **`bower install angular`** in terminal or **`sudo bower install angular`**, it says **`sudo: command not found`**.

What should I do to install add angular js in my application folder?

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. What output do you get when you run `bower install angular`? What Operating System do you have? Please note that you have to use the Bitnami console, to load it go to your installation directory and run `./use_meanstack` if you have a Unix system or go to Start -> BitNami Application Stack -> "Application console" or "Use Application Stack" if you have a Windows system. You will find more information using this [link](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/BitNami_console)

Comment: @JotaMartos I use Ubuntu 14.04 lts.

I used **`./use_meanstack`**, created **.bowerrc** file in my sample folder in which all the folders for the project are installed.

The output is:

**`root@userhost:~/MEAN_projects/FirstMeanApp/sample# sudo bower install angular`**

**`sudo: bower: command not found`**

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

I have been able to properly install AngularJS inside a new project folder as a non-root user without issues. First, I used the `./use_meanstack` and running command `which bower` returns:

> bitnami@localhost:~/MEAN_projects$ which bower
>
> /opt/meanstack-3.0.7-1/nodejs/bin/bower

Then, for installing AngularJS on a project, those are the command I run:

> mkdir -p /home/bitnami/MEAN_projects/test
>
> echo '{ "directory" : "public/javascripts/vendor" }' > /home/bitnami/MEAN_projects/test/.bowerrc
>
> cd /home/bitnami/MEAN_projects/test
>
> bower install angular

And that's what I got:

[image]

Also, when running `bower` using sudo, I got a message that recommends not to use bower with sudo:

[image]

Could you please try to reproduce my steps and check if it works for you?

Hope it helps,

Gonzalo